# Top of list-style-type emoji cut off in list (CSS)

Tags: css, firefox, utf-8, html-lists, emoji

The top of the emoji bullets (set by `list-style-type`) are cut off in my list in Firefox browser, but is fine in Chrome. Attempts at changing line height give the same cut-off results in Firefox. Very unfortunate. Any advice on how to show the full emoji in Firefox?

[image: Facepalm missing top of head in Firefox]

```css
<!---CSS--->

.mylist {
  margin-left: -1.5em;
  padding: 0;
}
.mylist ul li {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 2em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  list-style-position: outside;
}

.mylist ul ul li {
  font-style: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  list-style-type: "\1F926   ";
  list-style-position: inside;
  text-indent: -1.5em;
}
```

```html
<!---HTML--->

<div class="mylist">
    <ul>
      <li>List Item 1</li>
        <ul>
          <li> Sub item 1</li>
          <li> Sub item 2</li>
          <li> Sub item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Check line height vs. icon height.

Comment: @pavel can you be more specific? icon-height isn't a recognized css property. The icon seems to be directly tied to font-size. With font-size: 0.8em un ul ul li and line-height: 1.5em in both ul ul li and ul li the top of the emoji is still cut off.

Comment: In the fiddle here icon is showing correctly... Problem will be really in line heights, nothing else. Check in developer tools calculated icon height and LI line-height.

Comment: I checked it in Chrome and as you said, the fiddle works there. Seems to be an issue with Firefox, as adjusting line-heights shows no change. I've edited my question to clarify this.